# Express node sending file to DB or file upload

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

I am new to Express/Node environment and not aware of API and functionalites provided. We have Express 4 in our project and need to add feature where there will be couple file upload buttons. 
We thinking of storing files to DB ( SQL Server) table instead of file systems.
I experimented some examples and was able to upload file to file system ( using express-file-upload module). 
Now I want to try DB table which is desired way for our team and want to know best way per our needs.
I see options are

-busboy module
- multer
- simple file/path modules to open/read files and insert queries ( I am trying this method but don'nt know if it will work)

Please suggest right approach.
With same file upload button, now file will be stored in table. Table columns are

- file id
- blob,
- creation time
- user id

Any ideas or suggestions .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) as it abstracts much of the complexity of file uploads.

You can certainly store file blob in your database, but I wouldn't do it. This will make your database very large and backups could take long. See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not) stackexchange answer.

I highly recommend storing on the server itself or better, use [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). By using S3 you get all the benefits of AWS and a super low price. Then you store the S3 key in your database.

Comment: thanks for taking time to reply. I will try out multer. I was able to storage it locally using express-file-upload. I do not think having AWS will be an option for us. But I will definitely check out with our team. Do you know have few example on internet using S3 storage.  Just for learning.  We are restricted in terms of technology. We need to deploy node on IIS env with sql server db. If not, will go for server storage option.